# create form in head of main view template

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

I have a view template which contains head, menu, footer (I will call this file as main template). This template is called by other pages which have some content. I decided to add form for login into menu. My first idea was about pass form from view file which is rendered via controller into main template by parameter but I don't need show login form everytime on every page so this would't be my solution.

I have two solution but in both I have a problem:

1. I created form in main template with helper for form and input and button with pure html

   ```
   @helper.form(routes.Application.loginPosted,'class -> "navbar-form pull-right"){                                
   <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="email" name="email">
   <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="passwd" name="passwd">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
   }
   ```

   and I handle it in controller as DynamicForm and want it transfor into form which represent a model for easier validation

   ```
   DynamicForm requestData = form().bindFromRequest();
   Form<User_Login> loginFormFilled = form(User_Login.class);
   loginFormFilled.fill(new User_Login(requestData.get("email"), requestData.get("passwd")));
   ```

   but loginFormFilled.get().email (and passwd too) is always blank and I don't understand why.
2. I wanted create form in main template as a model representation but I can't write code which will be compile (it has problem with logForm I know that it is incorrect but I yet tried lots of combination but I can't create valid form)

   ```
   @val logForm = new Form[User_Login]
   @helper.form(routes.Application.loginPosted,'class -> "navbar-form pull-right"){
   @helper.inputText(
           logForm("email")
   )
   @helper.inputPassword(
           logForm("passwd")
   )
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `DynamicForm` binding for filling the `Form<User_Login>` you can do that at once (and probably that's solution for you):

```
public static Result loginApproach(){
    Form<User_Login> loginForm = form(User_Login.class).bindFromRequest();

    String formToString =
            loginForm.get().email + " with pass: " + loginForm.get().passwd;

    return ok(formToString);
}
```